# regex of symbolic expression grouped

Tags: python, regex

In python, I am trying to regex of a expression like this:

```
function_1(param_1,param_2,param_3)+function_2(param_4,param_5)*function_3(param_6)+function_4()-function_5(param_7,param_8,param_9,param_10)
```

I am using this regex

```
(?P<perf_name>\w*?)\((?P<perf_param>[\w]+)*(?:,*(?P<perf_param2>[\w]+)?)*\)
```

but I'm stuck because so far I can't get all the params_x which are not close to brackets (param_2, param_8 and param_9)

Plus, I am pretty sure there is some solution that would prevent me to use a single *perf_param* instead of the two *perf_param* and *perf_param2*

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be a lot easier by using multiple regexes, first to split the functions, then to get the parameters. Also, if functions can be nested (i.e. function calls as parameters) then this will be a problem with regex.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to give constraints onto operators between functions

Comment: Well, you can do it even with a single regex, but only with PyPi regex module. No idea if you can use it in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do that in 2 steps:

```
(?P<perf_name>\w*)\((?P<perf_params>\w*(?:,\w+)*)\)
```

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/kZ9vH7/2) will get you the name and params as two groups. Then, just split the second group with `,`.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?P<perf_name>\w*)\((?P<perf_params>\w*(?:,\w+)*)\)')
s = "function_1(param_1,param_2,param_3)+function_2(param_4,param_5)*function_3(param_6)+function_4()-function_5(param_7,param_8,param_9,param_10)"
res = [(x.group("perf_name"), x.group("perf_params").split(",")) for x in p.finditer(s)]
print(res)
# => [('function_1', ['param_1', 'param_2', 'param_3']), ('function_2', ['param_4', 'param_5']), ('function_3', ['param_6']), ('function_4', ['']), ('function_5', ['param_7', 'param_8', 'param_9', 'param_10'])]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RbK4An)

The regex matches:

- `(?P<perf_name>\w*)` - 0 or more alphanumeric/underscore characters
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `(?P<perf_params>\w*(?:,\w+)*)` - 0+ sequences of 0+ word characters (`\w*`) followed with 0+ sequences of 1+ word characters
- `\)` - closing `)`.